# How to Install PostgreSql on CentOS 6.9

Tags: postgresql, centos

I want to install **PostgreSql** on **CentOs 6.9** and create users through command line to help me in bluemail v5 installation but I tried some methods which are not working. Help.

Comment: If you expect that someone helps you, you should show some effort and not just write Help. You should first of all provide the "methods" you tried and the errors you got so people can understand what you are trying and where you are failing.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward. [there is an article for you to read.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-centos-6)

Comment: I couldn't understand the lines                                                                                    
<pre>
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os

baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
<span class=“highlight”>exclude=postgresql*</span> </pre>                                      Are <pre>  and  <span> to be included in command lines in shell   @Explorer